# How to run DotA on Ubuntu?

Tags: warcraft-3-the-frozen-throne, dota

Can anyone supply me with good links on a step-by-step process to run DotA on Ubuntu?

Comment: You may have better luck with our friends at askubuntu.com :)

Answer (score 14):

[**Wine**](http://www.winehq.org/) works.
Install:

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.7
```

Wine 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6 will also work.

Then just run Warcraft 3 from the terminal:

```
wine /path/to/warcraft.exe
```

If full screen will not work (happens with default Ubuntu video drivers) - run the game in window mode:

```
wine /path/to/warcraft.exe -window
```

To install latest versions of Wine you may need to add wine ppa repository and install like that:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.7
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you can also install it on [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) or even better vmplayer (more compatible with graphics) and play on [Garena](http://www.garena.com/) or [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi2/) online. [Here is a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NGZSlEERwFQ) where this is explained.

PS: you need a good video card that supports openGL to run it well

Answer (score 3):

You could also try Heroes of Newerth, which does provide an official Linux version.

Comment: Playing another game is hardly an acceptable solution

Comment: The second game is practically a port/remake of the first, just to provide some extra context to that answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should try [playonlinux](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/playonlinux).

Answer (score 0):

Warcraft 3 doesn't have an official Linux version, but you may have good results trying to run it with something like Cedega, Wine or Crossover Games.